# How to refer to a new class without changing the references in php

Tags: php, object-oriented-analysis

I have an OO architectural pattern question.
I think I made a mistake in the architecture but I don't have the time to refactor completely and "do-it-right".

So here goes:
In an existing PHP system I have "new Myclass"  and "if ($class instanceof  Myclass)" all over. Now I find that I want a new version of Myclass, but I don't have the bandwidth to change and test all the existing references to Myclass.

So I wonder if there is a pattern, available in php, that I can still keep my references to Myclass and do something such that it referes to MyclassV2 without changing every reference.

Preferably, I should be able to instantiate either the new or the old version.

I don't mind changing Myclass and/or adding new classes as needed.

Comment: Implement `interface`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I am not sure how an interface, which I see as a rule enforcer requiring the interface methods to exist, addresses my question.

Comment: Do these classes implement the same methods or not?

Comment: Yes they do implement the same methods.

Comment: So class extension should work fine in the answer below.  Except you probably want Myclass extending MyclassV2.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend `Myclass`.

```
class MyclassV2 extends Myclass {}

$MyclassV2 = new MyclassV2();
var_dump($MyclassV2 instanceof Myclass); // true
```

Comment: and then I would have to change all the reference in the system from Myclass to Myclass2. I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: you can keep `Myclass`. Above I've done an example, what's the problem? what you mean when you talk about `the reference`?